# The prop `checked` is marked as required in `ToggleSwitch`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, toggleswitch

In my reactjs project, when I onchange the toggleswitch, I am getting the error as

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `checked` is marked as required in `ToggleSwitch`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

I have an array which contains some values in which I need to map and to show the toggleswitch. my code is:

```
let [ischecked, setChecked] = useState({
        checkedA: true,
});
```

```
const handleSwitchChange = (event, func) => {
  setChecked(event);
};
```

```
Object.keys(arr).map((key, val) => (
<ToggleSwitch
className='onFunc'
defaultChecked={ischecked.checkedA}
onChange={(e)=>handleSwitchChange(e,key)}
name={`fun[${key}]`}
id={`on_${key}`}
optionLabels={["On", "Off"]}
value={ischecked.checkedA === true ? 'y' : 'n'}
/>
))
</td>
```

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w2mt.png)

Pleas help. I don't know how to fix the issue.

I need to remove the console eror when i click on the toggleswitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because in your `ToggleSwitch` component you have this :

```js
ToggleSwitch.propTypes = {
//...
  checked: PropTypes.boolean.isRequired
};
```

This means that your `ToggleSwitch` should recieve a property named `checked`.
so you have to pass it to the component :

```js
<ToggleSwitch
//...
checked={value} 
/>
```

if you don't really need it to be required you can remove `isRequired` :

```js
ToggleSwitch.propTypes = {
//...
  checked: PropTypes.boolean
};
```

so it will be optional

Comment: Thank for saving me form this error. but now I need to fix another pending console error which is "react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. "

Comment: did you removed `checked` or you add it to the component ?

Comment: try this : `checked={ischecked.checkedA === true ? true : false}`